# What is the limit for salesforce Recyclebin?

Tags: recycle-bin

suppose we will delete the records from recycle bin means where those records being(i mean which place those items saved). Is there any limit to get back those records(I mean Maximum how many days we can get those records).I used this query for get deleted records.

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE isdeleted = true ALL ROWS
```

Comment: if you delete them from recycle bin then you can't get them back using soql.

Comment: Yes...Using this query we can get just deleted record data only we can't restore those records. I m tring to know after deleting records from recyclebin where those records available.

Comment: no once you delete data from recycle bin you can't get them easily. You will need to contact SF support for this.

Comment: @user123 you can check below both ans. You will get your ans.. Or check your prev question where Tushar answered.

Answer (score 1):

- **Deleted data is only available for 15 days.** After 15 days, data is permanently deleted from the Recycle Bin, and if it hasn’t been backed up any other way, your only recourse is the Salesforce Data Recovery Service, which means it could take weeks to get your data back and cost a minimum of $10,000 USD.
- **Restoring deleted data is not available to all users.** Administrators and users with the “Modify All Data” permission are the only ones who can restore lost data from the Recycle Bin; all other users would have to contact them for assistance. This will result in lost productivity and create an additional burden to Salesforce administrators.
- **Doesn’t retain all versions of the data.** If a user accidentally changed a record before deleting it, they’ll only be able to recover the latest version with the incorrect information, not any previous correct or point-in-time versions which may be what the user actually wishes to restore.
- **Metadata is lost.** Any customizations, reports, dashboards, etc. cannot be restored and must be manually recreated. This can be painful and costly to rebuild these bits of information. In addition, if other processes or teams are dependent upon these customizations, more than just the user who lost data can be affected.

Sauce: http://spanning.com/blog/what-you-need-to-know-about-salesforces-recycle-bin/